# Inject remote ejb glassfish 4 with @producer error WELD-000044 Unable to obtain instance from null

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, weld

Well, I've got some problem injecting a remote stateless EJB into another stateless EJB using a producer with Glassfish 4.0 build 89 (development environment is NetBeans 7.0).
I will use a simplified naming for this purpose but my dev structure is roughly the same, that is:

- ProjectA (Enterprise Application - the one used by clients)

  - ProjectA-ejb
  - ProjectA-war
  - lib/ProjectB-ejbClient.jar
  - lib/ProjectB-jpa.jar
- ProjectB (Enterprise Application - behind the curtains)

  - ProjectB-ejb (Contains remote ejb impl)
- ProjectB-ejbClient (Java class library)

  - Contains remote interfaces, producer, qualifier and META-INF/beans.xml
- ProjectB-jpa (java class library)

  - Contains entites and META-INF/persistence.xml

**ProjectB** contains some authorization/management beans that will be used by many other projects (even on other servers) so they are remote. Later I will add a management webapp to it, so this is why it's an enterprise app and not a simple ejb project.
**ProjectA** instead is a complete enterprise project with ejb+webapp (and I could later add other enteprise projects ProjectC, D, etc) that uses ProjectB services.
Inside **ProjectB-jpa** are stored entites shared between management project (ProjectB) and single webapps (ProjectA and others).
Inside **ProjectB-ejbClient** class library I've writter the qualifier as this:

```
@Qualifier
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface RemoteManagement {    
}
```

and a bean factory producer as this:

```
public class ManagementBeanFactory {
    @Produces
    @RemoteManagement
    @EJB(lookup = "java:global/ProjectB/ProjectB-ejb/Management!it.mgmnt.ejb.ManagementRemote")
    private ManagementRemote managementRemote;
}
```

The beans.xml file is a plain JavaEE 7 template-like with attributes `version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all"` declared (I took it from Oracle tutorial).
Now, in ProjectA-ejb I have something like this:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class AccessControl {
    public final static String APPLICATION_CODE = "GDS";
    @Inject 
    @RemoteManagement
    //@EJB(lookup = "java:global/ProjectB/ProjectB-ejb/Management!it.mgmnt.ejb.ManagementRemote")
    private ManagementRemote mr;

    public String performLogin(final String username, final String password) {
        String uid = mr.authenticate(username, password, APPLICATION_CODE);
        return uid;        
    }

    //...
}
```

Projects are both deployed without any problem but when performLogin is called from the web tier I got a `javax.ejb.EJBException` with root cause `org.jboss.weld.exceptions.NullInstanceException: WELD-000044 Unable to obtain instance from null`.

I've debugged step-by-step and I found that `AccessControl.mr` is a reference to the remote bean and it's not null, so producer is generating a proxy to make the call.
If I swap `@Inject @RemoteManagement` annotatin with commented one `@EJB(lookup = "...")` everything works flawlessly.
I suspect that Weld is creating a proxy on `AccessControl.mr` property to the `ManagementBeanFactory.managementRemote` property that, I think, is null.
With debugger I discovered that the "toString()" references (printed on `AccessControl.mr`) are completely different between @Inject and @EJB and seems that @EJB has different "type" of generated proxy.
The strange thing is that I used to do the same thing with JBOSS AS 7.1.1Final using JavaEE 6 beans.xml (has different namespaces, etc) and it worked like a charm.

I don't know if I missed something in the producer/qualifier or if something has changed from JavaEE 6 to 7 (needed because I use a lot of stateless JSF views and @ViewScoped beans) on this field...or even if it's a Glassfish/Weld flaw (as I suspect).
I don't want to use Wildfly AS before it goes final and I would try to keep development and runtime in sync (same appserver) to have a more predictable environment.

If you even find errors or have suggestions in project structure/organization, please let me know. I'm glad to receive hint to get better project style.

Thank you for your help.